# The location of Rich Text area image repository

Tags: rest-api, knowledge, images, upload, richtextarea

Does anybody know how to access Rich Text area image repository programmatically? What is the object behind? I'd like to upload some files there and then reference them in the Rich Text content (everything without user intervention).

When inserting images manually, all of them have the same `eid` and `feoid`, the only difference is `refid`. I couldn't find this Id in Document or ContentDocument objects.

```
/servlet/rtaImage?eid={...}&feoid={...}&refid=0EM30000001GFrs
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you have id of a record, you can easily find the related object, using describe methods.

```
ID refid='0EM28000000I7Eq';

SYSTEM.DEBUG(refid.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName());
```

After describing all 3 ids, below are the objects

1. eid = Object which has the RTF field
2. feoid = Object Name 'CustomFieldDefinition'
3. refid = 'ContentReference'

Cheers.

Comment: It took me some time to learn Apex. I can reproduce your results now. That ContentReference seems to be the key, but I cannot access this SObject via REST API. When querying this object via Apex, there are suspicious properties: `isAccessible=false;isCreateable=false;isQueryable=false;isSearchable=false;isUpdateable=false;`.